# Uncommon latin year inscription

Tags: inscription

I found two inscriptions on a building in central Italy (both in Latin).
The first one describes how two guys with lots of titles decided to erect the building and it ends with a commonly seen A.D. MDCXXXII.

The second one states that the previous building collapsed and a new one was built by other two man with multiple titles. At the end it says "A.S. CDDCCLXXI".

What does this mean? I find it particularly strange that they use "A.S.", which I couldn't find on the list of abbreviations on Wikipedia, and "CDD", which I cannot make sense of (it would be too early if it meant 900). Does anyone know?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is an interesting question. If you happen to have a photo of the inscriptions, that would be helpful. You can add pictures to your question. There might be some useful little details and context there.

Comment: CD is an alternative for M:  I would guess the A.S. would be Year of our Salvation ; Anno Salvationis or of our Saviour; Salvatoris.

Comment: @Hugh Would you (or anyone else) like to post that as an answer? It answers the question, so it doesn't really belong in the comments.

Comment: @Hugh Thank you! As for the picture, I would've added one, but it was fairly dark and hard to read

Comment: @Hugh Good idea! _Anno salutis_, or maybe _salutaris_ makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect it says CǀƆǀƆCCLXXI = 1500 + 200 + 50 + 20 + 1 = 1771

But, as Joonas says, it would be helpful to see a photograph.

A.S. is "anno Salvatoris" (as Hugh has mentioned).

Comment: Thank you! "A.S." = "anno Salvatoris" makes sense. Also the year being 1771 is possible (the building is loosely neoclassical in style). Unfortunately I don't have a picture as it was too dark to take one (and the inscription was high up). Do you have a reference or other instances for "CǀƆǀƆ"? I distinctly recall the second letter being "D", not "ǀƆ". (to clarify, the year was the lowest line, so easiest to read)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#/media/File:Westerkerk_MDCXXX.jpg

Comment: @JohnDonne I've seen CǀƆD before, in a book from the eighteenth century, actually.